# Prove that $W$ is invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to linear operator $\mathcal{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

During the lecture I've missed out on, there was the following problem:

> Let $\mathcal{T}:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$, where linear operator $\mathcal{T}$ is defined by $\mathcal{T}(a,b,c,d)=(a+b+2c-d,b+d,2c-d,c+d)$, and let $W=\{(t,s,0,0)|t,s\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Check whether $W$ is invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to linear operator $\mathcal{T}$.

***Solution from the lecture:***

> We need to prove that $\forall w\in W$ it stands that $\mathcal{T}(w)\in W$, from the definition of invariant subspace. Let's take arbitrary $(t,s,0,0)\in W$. Then $\mathcal{T}(t,s,0,0)=(t+s,s,0,0)\in W$, hence $W$ is invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I don't understand how they just arrived to the conclusion $(t+s,s,0,0)\in W$. Why is this true when we know that vectors $(t,s,0,0)$ and $(t+s,s,0,0)$ are generated by linear combinations of two different vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(t,s,0,0)=t(1,0,0,0)+s(0,1,0,0)$$

and

$$(t+s,s,0,0)=(t+s)(1,0,0,0)+s(0,1,0,0)$$

so both them are generated by the same span$\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$

Comment: By that logic wouldn't it mean $span\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}=span\{(1,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0)\}$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.